# Google Map Tiles API - 403 Permission Denied

Tags: google-maps, google-map-tiles-api

I am trying to integrate the [Google Map Tiles API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile) into my web application. I've followed all prerequisite steps for setting up my account, project, billing, activating the API, and creating an API key. I have checked all settings 10 times, there are no configured restrictions that could get in the way.

Now, following the documentation, I'm starting with the POST request to create a new session:

```
curl -X POST -d '{
  "mapType": "streetview",
  "language": "en-US",
  "region": "US"
}' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
"https://tile.googleapis.com/tile/v1/createSession?key=<my key>"
```

Which fails with a HTTP 403 Permission denied error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Any idea what could still be wrong or missing here? The only suspicion I have is the top banner on the documentation page, which says:

> The Google Maps Platform Map Tiles API - 2D Tiles and Street View imagery are available to customers with specific imagery visualization use cases. If you're interested in this product, then Contact Sales.

Does that mean that I can't use this API without separate approval from the sales team (and potentially extra cost)? In that case, it would be misleading though that I can activate this API for my API key in my project.

Comment: Yes, you should contact sales to be able to use Tiles API. It would also be nice if you can file a [feature request](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker) with regards to your feedback.

Comment: FYI: Google Map Tiles API at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile is now generally available for Preview, including access to 2D and 3D tiles.